# QSet intersection from Qt not working

Tags: qt

This is so simple is mind boggling. But I can't see any error in the code:

```
QSet<int> A; A << 1 << 2 << 3 << 4;
QSet<int> B; B << 3 << 4 << 5 << 6;

qWarning() << "U:" << A.unite(B);
qWarning() << "Intersect:" << B.intersect(A);
```

According to the documentation I should get Interesect: QSet(3, 4) but I get

```
U: QSet(2, 3, 1, 6, 4, 5)
Intersect: QSet(3, 6, 4, 5)
```

What am I doing wrong? Is it a bug?

Comment: Shouldn't `QSet<int> B; A << 3 << 4 << 5 << 4;` be `QSet<int> B; B << 3 << 4 << 5 << 4;`?

Comment: Yes! But the problem still persists but in a different manner. I'm editing the question

Comment: Looks like it works as it should. `QSet::unite`: *Each item in the other set that isn't already in this set is inserted into this set.* So `A` will contain each value that `B` contains. This means that `B.intersect(A)` won't remove anything from `B`: *Removes all items from this set that are not contained in the other set.*

Comment: You are assuming that `A.unite(B);` won't modify the `A` object. It will.

Comment: Ahhh. Ok. I didn't know this. Thanks

Comment: @aarelovich It's not even something you're supposed to "know". You look at the method signature: is it const? If it's not, it modifies the object. Is `unite` a const method? No. Why? Because it modifies the object. It's a mutating method. Make sure you follow this convention when designing your own APIs: if a method is not supposed to mutate the object, you declare it const. That's the meaning of a const method: it's a contract. It literally means "I'm not changing this object". It's way better than documentation or comments: it's in C++, and everyone using C++ *should* know what it means.

Comment: What confused me was the fact the the method returns a QSet<type>, so I'd figure it would do that because it didn't modify the object. Why does it return a QSet then?

Comment: It returns a reference to a QSet, i.e.  QSet<type>&, so you can chain operations, and print it as you did here. If it didn't, something like A.unite(B).intersect(C) wouldn't be possible.

Comment: Ahh ok. Thanks for the clarification